# What's wrong with this swap function using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

Still a noob to programming in general. I know this code doesn't work but why?

```
void swap(int num1, int num2)
{ 
  int* p_first =& num1;
  int* p_sec =& num2;
  *p_first = num1;
  *p_sec = num2; 
}
```

Comment: Should be: 'void swap(int &num1, int &num2)' or 'void swap(int *num1, int *num2)' and adjust your code accordingly. Your parameters as they are, is passed by copy and not reference or pointer so you're swapping local copy of integers. There are many examples on SO and the Internet.

Comment: Related, in truth, should simply be `std::swap` wherever you're calling this from. No need to reinvent the wheel unless you are academically compelled to do so.

Comment: How do you know that the code doesn't work if you don't know why? What's your definition of "not working"? You should extract a minimal example including what happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: why do you write `=&`?

Comment: What do you think `swap(1,2);` would do? Change every `1` into a `2` and every `2` into a `1`? Modify the source code so it read `swap(2,1);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function takes its arguments by value, which means that the function is only operating on temporary copies of `num1` and `num2`.  The function modifies those values, and then when it returns, it throws away the temporary values, and the unchanged real values are kept.

The idiomatic C++ way to fix this is pass arguments by reference instead of value.

```
void swap(int &num1, int &num2) {
   auto temp = num1;
   num1 = num2;
   num2 = temp;
}

int x = 5, y = 7;
swap(x, y);
```

Alternatively, you can pass the arguments by pointer.  This is the idiomatic C way to do it (as C doesn't have references).  The disadvantage is that it forces the caller's code to pass the address of its arguments, rather than the arguments themselves.

```
void swap(int *num1, int *num2) {
   int temp = *num1;
   *num1 = *num2;
   *num2 = temp;
}

int x = 5, y = 7;
swap(&x, &y);
```

Of course, to swap two numbers, the **best** way is to not reinvent the wheel, and instead use `std::swap`, which is already written for you.

```
int x = 5, y = 7;
std::swap(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function does nothing at all, it look like a no-output function.

The reason is:
`num1`, `num2` are stack variables, you assign their address to `p_first` and `p_sec` which are also stack variable. Address of stack variable will be changed every time you execute the code.

And if you want to swap `num1` and `num2` why did you assign there values to two others variables (which make no sense).

At least you should think like this to swap them:

```
temp = num1
num1 = num2
num2 = temp
```

and because C++ will just *pass value* to function if you declare like this

```
void swap(int num1, int num2)
```

so you need to use pointer or reference to do it (the detail implementation could be searched easily):

```
void swap(int* num1, int* num2) //pointer parameter
void swap(int& num1, int& num2) //reference parameter
```

Answer (score -2):

1 - Here in the swap function you are using call by value so u cant get the result back in caller function.

2 - Implement the function given below ->

```
void swap(int num1, int num2) { 
    int temp;
    int* p_first =&num1;
    int* p_sec =&num2;
    temp = *p_first;
    *p_first = *p_sec;
    *p_sec = temp;
    printf("\n %d %d \n",num1,num2);
}
```

Swap will work now.

Comment: I'm not down voter. The code is terrible. You expect a `swap` function to do console I/O? `printf`? It's like `strlen` printing the length of string on console as output, and not return.

Comment: I _am_ a downvoter, for the reasons above. Your `swap` takes copies. What's the point? Why would anyone want to call a function, passing in two values, and have those values printed in a different order? The equivalent function is just `void swap(int n1, int n2) { std::cout << n2 << " " << n1 << std::endl };`